# What is the best way of separating "dev" and "prod" modes in the app?

Tags: node.js, express, structure, backend, apollo-server

Today I was trying to find a way to separate global variable between the modes: prod and dev.

I've hidden sensitive information in "process.env" using a third party module "dotenv" but it would still be very comfortable to have proper information there whether I am in a development mode or production. For instance, if I am working locally I am using my local or cloud test DB and when I am in a prod mode I'd like to have proper credentials for a real db. So it switches automatically depending on the current mode.

Below you can see what I have come up with so far. I would appreciate any recommendations or suggestions on the structure issue or practice, experience.

Thank you in advance!

server.js

```
import { environment } from "./environment";
import { apiExplorer } from "./graphql";
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { database } from "./utils/database";
import { logger } from "./utils/logging";
import { verify } from "./utils/jwt";

database.connect();

apiExplorer.getSchema().then((schema) => {

  // Configure express
  const port = environment.port;
  const app = express();

  // Configure apollo
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req, res }) => {
      const context = [];

      // verify jwt token
      context.authUser = verify(req, res);

      return context;
    },

    formatError: (error) => {
      logger.error(error);
      return error;
    },

    debug: true

  });
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

  app.listen({ port }, () => {
    logger.info(`Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`);
  });

})
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error('Failed to load api', err);
  })
```

db class

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { environment } from "../environment";
import { logger } from './logging';

class Database {

  constructor() {
    this._database = 'MongoDB';
    this._username = environment.db.username;
    this._password = environment.db.password;
    this._dbName = environment.db.name;
  }

  connect() {
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    const url = `mongodb+srv://${this._username}:${this._password}@cocoondb-qx9lu.mongodb.net/${this._dbName}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

    try {
      mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
      mongoose.connection.once('open', () => logger.info(`Connected to ${this._database}`));
      mongoose.connection.on('error', err => logger.error(err));
    } catch (e) {
      logger.error(`Something went wrong trying to connect to the database: ${this._database}`)
    }
  }
}

export const database = new Database();
```

environment/index.js

```
import { development } from './develepment';
import { production } from './production';
import { merge } from "lodash"

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV ? 'production' : 'development';
const values = process.env.NODE_ENV ? production : development;

export const environment = merge(values, { mode });
```

development.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

export const development = {
  port: 8080,
  db: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    name: process.env.DB_NAME
  }
};
```

production.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

export const production = {
  port: process.env.PORT,
  newfromproduction: 'jkdl',
  db: {
    test: 'test'
  }
};
```

```
file structure

src
   -environment
      - index.js
      - development.js
      - production.js
   -graphql
   -models
   -utils
   server.js

.babelrc
.env
.gitignore
package.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right path. Abstracting away the environment-specific configuration is the way to go in my opinion.

Here are a couple of remarks to enhance your code:

- I don't think you necessarily need `dotenv` or even `merge` from `lodash` to make sure that your application code runs regardless of the environment it is in.
- The object you export from `environment/index.js` should have the same shape for all environments to avoid errors that occur only in one environment, which is not the case in the snippets you provided.
- I would suggest using JSON instead of JS for your config, but that's just a preference.
- I would advise to use as little environment variables as possible. You can simply rely on `NODE_ENV` (or whatever single environment variable name you want) and make sure that it is defined when you run your `npm start` script.

Here is the code of what I would recommend to do (where ALL_CAPS strings should be replaced by the actual values you need for your app to run in that environment):

*development.json*

```
{
  "port": 8080,
  "db": {
    "username": "DEVELOPMENT_USERNAME",
    "password": "DEVELOPMENT_PASSWORD",
    "name": "DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_NAME"
  },
  "newfromproduction": ""
}
```

*production.json*

```
{
  "port": 8080,
  "db": {
    "username": "PRODUCTION_USERNAME",
    "password": "PRODUCTION_PASSWORD",
    "name": "PRODUCTION_DATABASE_NAME"
  },
  "newfromproduction": "jkdl"
}
```

*environment/index.js*

```
import development from './development.json';
import production from './production.json';

const { NODE_ENV: mode } = process.env;

const configuration = {
  development,
  production
};

// using a little bit of destructuring magic but that is not necessary
export default { ...configuration[mode], mode };
```

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server",
  "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon server"
}
```

And you can keep the code in `server.js` the same.

A couple benefits for this approach:

- You don't have to commit `development.json` and `production.json` in your repository, so your password is safe from developers who don't need to know what it is. If a developer needs the config file to work on the app, simply share an encrypted version of `development.json` with them. It's not ideal but at least your password is not stored in plaintext in GitHub.
- If you need to add other environments (such as `test` or `stage`), you only need to create a JSON file in the `environment` folder and add a script in `package.json` (for example `"start:stage": "NODE_ENV=stage node server"` or `"test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha"`). No need to add `if` statements in `environment/index.js`.

A small downside:

- If the value of `NODE_ENV` is a string for an environment that is not expected (such as `NODE_ENV=abc123`) then the app will crash because `configuration.abc123` is `undefined`, but that is not necessarily a bad thing (having unexpected environments is not a good idea) and you can also ameliorate the code I provided to handle that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: I just thought that the sensitive information should be stored somewhere in the system environment and be gitignored (excluding .env file). I have never worked with environment before and after skimming over a huge number of articles people recommended to use DOTENV. I would really like to write it without it a thief party module just to improve my skills. And I used LODASH because at first I thought there would be a lot of information to merge. YES! I do agree that both environments should be similar with the same structure. I was on that but wanted to hear others opinions at first.

Comment: Yes, I set the variable in my script when I start the app

Comment: As I mentioned in the benefits of this approach, you don't have to commit the config. Please make sure to read and understand the answer before downvoting it. You can use `dotenv` and `lodash` if you want but it's not a necessity, even for complex config files. I've been working with applications that run in multiple environments on AWS for the last 2 years, so I know a thing or two on the subject. In fact, using something like AWS Secrets Manager is much more suitable to store sensitive information. If you find a better approach than this one, I would be curious to hear it.

Comment: Actually I upvoted it when it had already been downvoted. I appreciate your help and I’m always curious to hear others. I’d like to improve my skills and experience in programming and to hear someone skilled and experienced in the field is very important for me

Comment: Yes, I read it carefully and I got your point about json files of config. I think it’s a good idea

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! I might have been a little bit defensive here. I hope my answer helped. If you find that it satisfies your question please select it as a valid answer :) Let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: Yes, it helped. But I’ll leave it open for a while in case someone else has any ideas on that. I always have a lot of questions. I would appreciate if you stay near  somewhere here

Comment: Sounds good! If you want to ask question to me directly you can reach me on Twitter: https://twitter.com/yvesgurcan or LinkedIn: https://linkedin.com/in/yvesgurcan.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yves!